# How do I switch from rawhide to the usual packages using dnf?

Tags: fedora, dnf

dnf is installing packages from rawhide. How do I get it to use the regular packages?

The system is fc35.x86_64.

Comment: Fedora 35 has the release date set to 'Oct 19, 2021'. .... And Fedora 35 is the current "Rawhide development version".

Comment: In the end, I reinstalled Fedora (34).